# How to use aggregations framework in new Elasticsearch using Perl language

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

I am working on Elasticsearch and I have to do aggregations (i.e used for summarize our data) I shared my code below....

**CODE:**

```
 my $portal_es = Search::Elasticsearch->new(nodes => [$es_ip.':'.$es_port],request_timeout => 180); 
    my $result = $portal_es->scroll_helper(index => 10002500,size =>"10000", params=>{rest_total_hits_as_int =>true},{
      #"size": 0,
     aggs=> {
        "my-agg-name"=> {
          terms=> {
            field=> "tcode"
          }
        }
      }
});
```

I am getting following error

```
[Param] ** Expecting a HASH ref or a list of key-value pairs, called from sub Search::Elasticsearch::Role::Client::Direct::Main::scroll_helper at /home/prity/Desktop/BL_script/search_index_processor/aggregation.pl line 15. With vars: {'params' => ['index','10002500','size','10000','params',{'rest_total_hits_as_int' => 'true'},{'aggs' => {'my-agg-name' => {'terms' => {'field' => 'tcode'}}}}]}
```

Comment: Do you have a function or constant (same thing) called `true`? I think you are not showing us your real code, as the error message seems to have a string `'true'` there.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure in your argument list is probably broken.

```
my $result = $portal_es->scroll_helper(
   index  => 10002500,
   size   => "10000", 
   params => {
     rest_total_hits_as_int => 'true'
   },
   {                          # <---- here
     aggs => {
     # ...
```

You are passing a list of key/value pairs into the `scroll_helper`, but there is one extra last argument after `params`. It's a hash reference with `aggs` in it that has no key for it.

Turn on `use warnings` and you'll get a warning that your data structure is missing a value (because that hashref will stringify into a key).

You probably shouldn't have closed the hashref for `params` and opened a new one. But that's just a guess, I don't know what this method expects.